# Increase value of counter by one upon class creation/append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Creating a system that increases the 'fault' counter by a value of one upon every wrong answer submitted. I'm doing this by having my system listen out for the creation of a class called "incorrectResponse". However, it appears to just add to the counter as soon as the page finishes loading and doesn't add any more values after that.

Here is the code I've tried that isn't working.

```
  //*-- Fault counter --*//
  if (document.querySelectorAll('incorrectResponse')) {
    $('#fault-counter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
  };
```

Any reason as to why this is the case?

Comment: _I'm doing this by having my system listen out for the creation of a class_ - where is the code that listens?

Comment: As @Maximus points out, where is your event listener?

Comment: `incorrectResponse` or `.incorrectResponse`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('incorrectResponse')` looks for *elements* like `<incorrectResponse></incorrectResponse>`, not CSS classes. See @PranavCBalan's comment. Obviously if you run that code only at the load of the document, it will only be called ... at the load of the document.

Comment: Sorry, I've been utilizing things such as getElementById and querySelectorAll to look out for ID's and classes being created from appends/prepends. I'm not the greatest jQuery developer around, so I'm assuming there is a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming you're using jQuery (you mention it in one of your comments), one thing you could do is attach an event listener to the container of your 'wrong answers'.

A custom event would be triggered manually any time a wrong answer is received/appended to the page and the event listener would react to it recalculating the number of wrong answers and updating the counter.

```js
function updateNumberOfIncorrectMsgs() {
  $('.counter').text($('.incorrectAnswer').length);
}

updateNumberOfIncorrectMsgs();
var $container = $('.wrongAnswersContainer')
  .on('newWrongAnswerAdded', function() {
    updateNumberOfIncorrectMsgs();
  });

// The for and setTimeout is only to simulate msgs appended to the page, the important part is the custom event that gets triggered when an element is added.
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $container
      .append('<p class="incorrectAnswer">Incorrect answer</p>')
      .trigger('newWrongAnswerAdded');
  }, 1000 * i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Incorrect answer counter: <span class="counter"></span>
</p>
<div class="wrongAnswersContainer"></div>
```

Comment: This is great, I was able to modify this code to get the result I needed. Really appreciate the time on this one mate! Upvoted! :)